# Main destination in Schengen and non-Schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen, croatia

I intend to visit Croatia along with Bosnia and Serbia (non-Schengen) with my multiple-entry Schengen Croatian visa.

My visa is valid from the 29th of September until 30th of October with a duration of 18 days.

Does my duration of stay in Croatia need to be longer than in Bosnia and Serbia combined (main destination)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is your main destination Croatia, or is your main destination Bosnia and Serbia?

Comment: I intend to spend more days in Bosnia and Serbia combined than in Croatia alone, though my first entry is Croatia

Comment: Exactly! So I need not worry spending more time in other non schengen countries with croatia being my sole schengen destination. Thank you very much 

Comment: I need to add that my visa is only valid for 18 days.

Answer (score 3):

Since Croatia is your **only** destination inside the Schengen Area, it is (as far as the visa is concerned) your **main** destination.

Going to Bosnia and Serbia helps to insure that a multi-entry visa will be issued.

Comment: So I need not worry about spending more days outside Croatia? My visa is only valid for 18 days I must add, so no other visit will be programmed to Croatia  after my trip

Comment: If the visa is valid from date X to Y, then you can reenter only inside these dates. If the visa is valid for one year **but** only allows 18 days inside the Schengen Area (duration), then the full days inside the Schengen Area count. (This should be part of your question)

Comment: My visa is valid from the 29th of September until 30th of October with a duration of 18 days. I will travel mid october and intend to spend more days in Bosnia and Serbia combined than in Croatia alone, though my first country of entry will be Croatia. Does this make the latter still my main destination. Thank you very much for taking the time I tried to ask the embassy in my country but no answer could be given for sure

Comment: The main destination question is only asked to determine which Schengen country should issue the visa. You already have the visa, so this has been resolved. Enjoy your trip.

Comment: I’ve heard I need to spend more days in the main destination (country issuing the visa). I now understand that since Croatia is my sole schengen destination, I should not worry about this. Thanks a lot 